# ImportError: cannot import name 'LegacyInstallFailure' from 'pip._internal.exceptions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req import InstallRequirement
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/XXXX/venv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import InstallationError, LegacyInstallFailure
ImportError: cannot import name 'LegacyInstallFailure' from 'pip._internal.exceptions'
```